# Type Descriptor File for StanfordCore NLP for Apache UIMA RUTA

Tags: stanford-nlp, uima, ruta, typedescriptor, dkpro-core

I am trying to annotate a text in German literature in Apache UIMA by writing rules in RUTA. I am using DKPro Core as well. I am very new to this and figuring out how to do stuff.
I am unable to get few annotations which are not mentioned in TypeDescriptor files as generated by the example German Novels (https://github.com/apache/uima-ruta/tree/trunk/example-projects/GermanNovels).

**For example**: ADJA tag in Partofspeech tagset that is available in Standford NLP POS tagger.

I searched for Typedescriptor file for StanfordCoreNLP but couldn't find on the net.
How can I generate these files?

Comment: Do you mean [POS_ADJ](https://dkpro.github.io/dkpro-core/releases/1.10.0/docs/typesystem-reference.html#type-de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core.api.lexmorph.type.pos.POS_ADJ)? Fine-grained values are stored in the feature `PosValue `.

Comment: We referred to German Novel exam in which there are limited number of pos tags. We need to use more accurate tags such as ADJA,VVFIN which are specific to the German language. We need a type descriptor which will generate these all tags for us. Can you help us with the type descriptors?

Comment: I do not think that you need separate types, but maybe you need match on the fine-grained information stored in that feature like POS_ADJ.PosValue=="ADJA".

Comment: At the time when the German Novels example was written, DKPro Core POS types were still a bit different (like ~1.8.0). Either you have to use the example with an older DKPro Core version form before when then `POS_` prefixes were added, or the rules need to be rewritten for the new types. Cf. https://github.com/dkpro/dkpro-core/issues/76 and https://github.com/dkpro/dkpro-core/issues/414